# Camera causing flutter application to crash

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package for Flutter.

Every time the app is running, if I try to change the camera permission from the settings of iOS device the app crashes. So I created a new application and used the [example code](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/camera/camera/example/lib/main.dart) available on their website.

The app still crashes. I am only using the code as it is with nothing else, no other package or code.

To replicate, run application with camera package. Once the app is running and you can see the camera view, go to Settings of your iOS device and change camera permission for the application to Off.

Error Log

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGKILL
    frame #0: 0x00000001bb586aac libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 8
libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap:
->  0x1bb586aac <+8>: ret
libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_overwrite_trap:
    0x1bb586ab0 <+0>: mov    x16, #-0x20
    0x1bb586ab4 <+4>: svc    #0x80
    0x1bb586ab8 <+8>: ret
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
Lost connection to device.
Exited
```

How to fix this issue?

**Scenario**:
The user has denied the camera permission before launching the application. The user wants to take a picture so the application prompts the users to head to settings to grant the necessary permission.

**Current Result:**
The app crashes as soon as the user grants the permission

**Expected Result:**
The user should be able to change the permission to granted, and move back to the application without the app crashing.

Comment: What does the log say can you please mention the log as well?

Comment: Check  the camera permission

Comment: What would you expect to happen? If you are using the camera and tell the OS that the app is not allowed to use the camera, killing the app seems to be inside what I would say is "reasonable behavior".

Comment: @nvoigt Other apps which use camera don't crash if you switch the permission off. And by others I mean those available on App Store.

Comment: What do they do instead?

Comment: @nvoigt Ok so here is a scenario. The user has set the Camera Permission = Denied. The normal behaviour is to show the user a screen informing of the same. Ask them to go to the settings and change the permission to Allowed. Now when the user goes to settings to change the permission, as soon as he changes it the app crashes.

Comment: I'm afraid even after the third try, you have not actually answered my very simple question: what *do you expect to happen* as "correct"? What do other apps do, that you deem "correct"?

Comment: @nvoigt the user is able to grant the permission and return back to the app without it crashing.

Comment: Sorry, I give up. You have evaded my question what it should **do** *instead* for the fourth time now.

Comment: @nvoigt  I have been trying to respond to your question repeatedly but it seems I am unable to pass my message across. I simply don't want the app to crash. I want the user to be able to change the permission to granted if it is denied without the app crashing. I don't. know how else to phrase it to answer your question.

Comment: I don't want to know what you *don't* want. I want to know what happens in other apps *instead* and more importantly, what you want to happen *instead*.

Comment: @nvoigt In other applications for example WhatsApp, if the user has denied the camera permission before launching the application and they want to use the camera feature they are prompted with the message" WhatsApp does not have access to your camera. To enable access, tap Settings and turn on Camera." The user is able to go to the settings, change the camera permission to granted and come back to WhatsApp and use the camera without the application crashing. I want the same. I want to be able to leave the application, go to Settings, change permission and come back to the application.